# Github pages not showing loaded angular app

Tags: github, github-pages

Attempting a test  deploy of this repository using github pages:

```
https://github.com/fireflysemantics/help-service-parts/blob/gh-pages/index.html
```

The `base href` in `index.html` is set to:

```
href="https://fireflysemantics.github.io/help-service-parts/">
```

And it redirects to the custom domain setup for this repository:

```
  https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/
```

The `index.html` page loads (Per checking the console), but none of the `*.js` resources load.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

OK - The `base href` has to be set to the custom domain URL:

```
<base href="https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Now this works:

```
https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/
```

Here's a complete tutorial:

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/deploying-your-angular-application-to-github-pages-3781727779e1